# Need help on Bar Chart Plot

Tags: android

I need help on plotting the bar chart to show daily based statistics like below attached image[image] shown on iPhone App to android, can you any suggest the corresponding api for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the open source [chartdroid](https://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/)? Looks like it uses native Android Intents to graph, although the Chartdroid library is required.